# Mute Volume with Minimal Re-encoding

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, volume, mute

Is it possible to mute a section of a video file (say 5 seconds) without having to re-encode the whole audio stream with ffmpeg?  I know it's technically (though probably not easily) possible by reusing the majority of the existing audio stream and only re-encoding the changed section and possibly a short section before and after, but I'm not sure if ffmpeg supports this.  If it doesn't, anyone know of any other library that does?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the partial segmented encode, as you suggest, but if the source codec is DCT-based such as AAC/MP3, there will be glitches at the start and end of the re-encoded segment once you stitch it all back together.

You would use the segment muxer and concat demuxer to do this.

```
ffmpeg -i input -vn -c copy -f segment -segment_time 5 aud_%d.m4a
```

Re-encode the offending segment, say `aud_2.m4a` to `noaud_2.m4a`.

Now create a text file

```
file aud_0.mp4
file aud_1.mp4
file noaud_2.mp4
file aud_3.mp4
```

and run

```
ffmpeg -an -i input -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy new.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the small [sample file](https://samples.ffmpeg.org/MPEG-4/fridayafternext_http.mp4).

Here is my plan visualized:

```
# original video

|                video              |
|                audio              |


# cut video into 3 parts. Mute the middle part.

|   video   |   | video |   |     video     |
|   audio   |   |   -   |   |     audio     |


# concatenate the 3 parts     

|   video   | video |     video     |
|   audio   |   -   |     audio     |


# mux uncut original video with audio from concatenated video

|                video              |
|   audio   |   -   |     audio     |
```

Let's do this.

Store filename:

```
i="fridayafternext_http.mp4"
```

To mute the line *"What the hell are you doing in my house!?"*, the silence should start at second `34` with a duration of `2` seconds.

Store all that for your convenience:

```
mute_starttime=34
mute_duration=2
```

`bash` supports simple math so we can automatically calculate the start time where the audio starts again, which is `36` of course:

```
rest_starttime=$(( $starttime + $duration))
```

Create all 3 parts. Notice that for the 2nd part we use `-an` to mute the audio:

```
ffmpeg -i "$i" -c copy -t $mute_starttime start.mp4 && \
ffmpeg -i "$i" -ss $mute_starttime -c copy -an -t ${mute_duration} muted.mp4 && \
ffmpeg -i "$i" -ss $rest_starttime -c copy rest.mp4
```

Create `concat_videos.txt` with the following text:

```
file 'start.mp4'
file 'muted.mp4'
file 'rest.mp4'
```

Concat videos with the `Concat demuxer`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_videos.txt -c copy muted_audio.mp4
```

Mux original video with new audio

```
ffmpeg -i "$i" -i "muted_audio.mp4" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy "${i}_partly_muted.mp4"
```

**Note:**

I've learned from [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68250600/6444590) that you do the last 2 steps in 1 take which is really cool.

```
ffmpeg -an -i "$i" -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_videos.txt -c copy "${i}_partly_muted.mp4"
```